# How to delete all rows in a Greenplum row oriented table

Tags: delete, disk-space, greenplum

In Greenplum, what is the best practice to delete all rows from a table? DELETE FROM TABLE or TRUNCATE TABLE? I dont have any child tables or foreign key constraints.

Answer (score 0):

Since Greenplum uses the Postgres database engine, reasoning applicable to a Postgres database seems appropriate. I don't see any reason *not* to use `TRUNCATE` when deleting all rows in a table with no children or foreign keys (which is your case), *unless* you have the `ON DELETE` triggers that you want to fire.